Integer coefficients and continued fractions

Let $a(n,p,q)$ be the family of integer sequences such that ordinary generating functions for it are $\frac{1}{G_1(0,x)}$ where $G_1(0,x)$ are continued fractions such that
$$
G_1(j,x)=1-\cfrac{(qj+1)x}{1-\cfrac{p(j+1)x}{G_1(j+1,x)}}.
$$
Note that
$$
G_1(0,x)=1-\cfrac{x}{1-\cfrac{px}{1-\cfrac{(q+1)x}{1-\cfrac{2px}{1-\cfrac{(2q+1)x}{1-\cfrac{3px}{1-\cfrac{(3q+1)x}{1-\cfrac{4px}{\ddots}}}}}}}}.
$$
Let $b(n,p,q)$ be the family of integer sequences such that ordinary generating functions for it are $\frac{1}{G_2(0,x)}$ where $G_2(0,x)$ are continued fractions such that
$$
G_2(j,x)=1-(qj+1)x-\cfrac{p(j+1)x}{G_2(j+1,x)}.
$$
Note that
$$
G_2(0,x)=1-x-\cfrac{px}{1-(q+1)x-\cfrac{2px}{1-(2q+1)x-\cfrac{3px}{1-(3q+1)x-\cfrac{4px}{\ddots}}}}.
$$
Let
$$
T_1(n,k,p,q) = (q(k-1)+1)T_1(n-1,k,p,q) + p(n-k+1)T_1(n-1,k-1,p,q), \\
T_1(n,1,p,q) = [n > 0], \\
T_1(n,0,p,q) = T_1(0,k,p,q) = 0.
$$
Here square bracket denotes Iverson bracket.
Let
$$
T_2(n,k,p,q) = (q(k-1)+1)T_2(n-1,k,p,q) + p(n+k-3)T_2(n-1,k-1,p,q), \\
T_2(n,1,p,q) = [n > 0], \\
T_2(n,0,p,q) = T_2(0,k,p,q) = 0.
$$

I conjecture that for $n>0$
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}T_1(n,k,p,q) = a(n,p,q), \\
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}T_2(n,k,p,q) = b(n-1,p,q).
$$
Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:
a(n,p,q) = my(CF = 1); for(j=0, n, CF = 1 - x*(q*(n-j)+1)/(1 - p*x*(n-j+1)/CF) + x*O(x^n)); polcoeff(1/CF, n)
b(n,p,q) = my(CF = 1); for(j=0, n, CF = 1 - x*(q*(n-j)+1) - p*x*(n-j+1)/CF + x*O(x^n)); polcoeff(1/CF, n)
upto1(n,p,q) = my(v1); v1 = vector(n, i, a(i, p, q))
upto2(n,p,q) = my(v1); v1 = vector(n, i, b(i-1, p, q))
upto3(n,p,q) = my(v1); v1 = vector(n, i, 0); v1[1] = 1; v2 = v1; for(i=2, n, v1 = vector(n, j, if(j==1, 1, (q*(j-1)+1)*v1[j] + p*(i-j+1)*v1[j-1])); v2[i] = vecsum(v1)); v2
upto4(n,p,q) = my(v1); v1 = vector(n, i, 0); v1[1] = 1; v2 = v1; for(i=2, n, v1 = vector(n, j, if(j==1, 1, (q*(j-1)+1)*v1[j] + p*(i+j-3)*v1[j-1])); v2[i] = vecsum(v1)); v2
test1(n,p,q) = upto1(n,p,q) == upto3(n,p,q)
test2(n,p,q) = upto2(n,p,q) == upto4(n,p,q)

Is there a way to prove it?

Confused.  Did you tell us what $a(n)$ and $b(n-1)$ are?  Maybe $p,q$ are fixed, and then ignored in the notation?  But stiil, $a(n,p,q)$ is a family of sequences?  What is $x$?

@GeraldEdgar, thank you for comment! Done.

What's the origin of this question? What prompted you to look at these particular continued fractions, these particular generating functions? Without some sense of the background here it's hard to even suggest good directions to look in for a proof.

@StevenStadnicki, thank you for comment! I just searched the encyclopedia for sequences corresponding to special cases of the sum of integer coefficients, and then intuitively made a generalization.
